# Microsoft LCS 2005 not able to login to server

Tags: active-directory, sql-server-2008-r2, subdomain, communication

I had an LCS server installed on my test environment and it was working fine. Recently I had to change the Domain name and domain controller name of the AD machine, to which this LCS-machine is connected as a client.

After the Domain name and DC name changes, I'm not able to run the LCS 2005 server in the MMC snap-in environment I keep getting the

> 'The computer is not part of a domain, network connection is lost'

message, though I'm able to login to the LCS machine in within the domain and the properties  also show that the computer is part of the new Domain-name.

Please suggest as what might have gone wrong and what I can do to get this running.

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding it to the domain?  I'd try that as changing the name of the DC has probably broken the trust relationship between the machine, it's likely that you are logging on with cached credentials, masking the issue.